# How to pass variable that is a template to template?

Tags: twig

If I want to pass a variable to template, that is by itself an other  template, how can I do this?

In drupal twig templates, for example, variables are templates.
I built a template, `index.html.twig`, which contains a variable for the template `page.html.twig` in the body tag:

`[[ page ]]`

In `index.php` I initialize twig loader, environment and load `index.html.twig` in the variable `$index` and `page.html.twig` in the variable `$page`.

So, I create an `array` with the indices `title` and `page` and pass it towards the render function of `$index`.
The `page` index insside the array is to `$page->render()`

When I call `$index->render($variables)` it displays the contents of `index.html.twig` and `page.html.twig`. But the `page.html.twig` tags are visible...
It replaces with `<`with `&lt;` (e.g *`&lt;div&gt;`*) etc.

Any idea to solve this problem? It is possible?

Comment: Some sample code would be great. Right now its kind of hard to follow your question.

Comment: Can't u just do an include rather than passing the other template to twig as well? I mean it's possible right. You could do sthing like $tpl = `$twig->loadTemplate('mytemplate.twig');` and pass it to twig and then do sthing like `{{ tpl.render({'foo':'bar',}) | raw }}` but that seems devious